# How do you use Gatling's checkIf method?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Documented [here](https://gatling.io/docs/current/cheat-sheet/), Gatling's `checkIf` method is intended for conditional checking. It's not available on `ScenarioBuilder`'s fluent API but I can see it in the `CheckSupport` class. I have scoured the internet and cannot find a single example.

I'm using Gatling 2.3.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found [an example](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/f7a8bdcd7f891b799a0c89e4a35bf05feefa6869/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/compile/HttpCompileTest.scala#L232) in their unit tests as follows:

```scala
http("untypedCheckIf").get("/")
      .check(
        checkIf("${bool}") {
          jsonPath("$..foo")
        }
      )
```

Comment: I like idea ... most of Gatling docs doesn't have proper code snippets. finding it at their unitest is best place :)

Answer (score 0):

Under Gatling 3.7.6, this worked for me:

```java
http("Test Gatling checkIf()")
    .get("/")
    .check(status().in(200, 404).saveAs("httpStatus"))
    .checkIf(session -> "200".equals(session.getString("httpStatus")))
        .then(
            jmesPath("someField")
                .saveAs("fieldName"))
    .checkIf(session -> "404".equals(session.getString("httpStatus")))
        .then(
            jmesPath("someField")
                .withDefault("some default value")
                .saveAs("fieldName"));
```